# How to calculate totals in datasets with GroupBy applied to Values

Tags: dataset, gathering

I have the following Dataset:

```
ExData = Import["Example.xlsx", {"Dataset", 1}, "HeaderLines" -> 1];
```

[image]

I would like to get the total of Stage1+Stage2 and Stage3+Stage4+Stage5 grouping by Supplier but I am not able to extend the instruction:

```
ExData[GroupBy[#[["Supplier"]] &], GroupBy[#[["Stage"]] &], Total, #[["Amount"]] &]
```

which gives:

[image]

to get GroupBy work in combination with values. Is there a clever way to use GroupBy for this purpose? Thanks !

Comment: Provide sample data that can be copied and pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a variation of `data` from Alan's answer:

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = Dataset@
  Table[Association["Sector" -> RandomChoice[{"Energy", "Env"}], 
    "Supplier" -> StringTemplate["N``"]@RandomInteger[5], 
    "Stage" -> "Stage" <> ToString[RandomInteger[{1, 5}]], 
    "Amount" -> 1000*RandomInteger[200]], 100]
```

[image]

```
data[GroupBy["Supplier"], 
 GroupBy[Switch[#Stage, "Stage1" | "Stage2", "stages12", _, "stages345"] &], 
 Total, "Amount"]
```

[image]

Alternatively, use `KeySort` to reorganize the output:

```
data[GroupBy["Supplier"] /* KeySort, 
 GroupBy[Switch[#Stage, "Stage1" | "Stage2", "stages12", _, "stages345"] &] /* KeySort, 
 Total, "Amount"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Edited in response to change in question added in a comment:*

```
data = Dataset@Table[Association[
     "Sector" -> RandomChoice[{"Energy", "Env"}],
     "Supplier" -> StringTemplate["N``"]@RandomInteger[5],
     "Stage" -> StringTemplate["Stage``"]@RandomInteger[5],
     "Amount" -> 1000*RandomInteger[200]
     ], 100];
grp = GroupBy["Supplier"]
data[grp, Total, "Amount"]
```

Your comment says you only want to total over a Stage1 and Stage 2, so select for these.

```
sel = Select["Stage1" == #Stage || "Stage2" == #Stage &]
data[sel][grp, Total, "Amount"]
```

Comment: Thank you, but you are not grouping by values here. What I am looking for is to get the sum of only Stage1 and Stage2, which are two values of "Stage". The subtle syntax you kindly suggested is equivalent to: ExData[GroupBy["Supplier"], Total, "Amount"].

Comment: @Massolo Your comment does not match your question.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear in the first place, it works, thanks a lot